# Apply colormap when plotting array in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to apply a colormap when plotting an array of numbers in Julia 1.4.1, but all plot entries appear to only use the first color in the map. For instance:

```
using Plots

plot([1:10], rand(10,5), c=:viridis)
```

No colour change occurs even when I increase the number of plot entries to 1000:

```
plot([1:10], rand(10,1000), c=:viridis)
```

I have tried to apply the map using `color` or `cgrad` too, but had no success. So this leaves me wondering: how can I apply this colourmap such that it correctly spans the number of plot entries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want each line to use a different color?
I think you are looking for the `palette` argument.

#### First,create the color palette based on viridis, as suggested by Anshul in the comments (see end for alternative method).

```
julia> using Plots

julia> p = Plots.palette(:viridis, 11)
```

In the last code, 11 is the number of lines

#### Now, [let's plot using the `palette` argument](https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/generated/colorschemes/).

```
julia> plot( [1:10], rand(10,11), palette=p )
```

#### Alternative method to create the palette is [creating a color gradient function](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/ExamplePlots.jl/blob/master/notebooks/cgrad.ipynb)

```
julia> C(g::ColorGradient) = RGB[ g[z] for z in range(0,stop=1,length=11) ]
```

#### We define the palette using that function

```
julia> g = :viridis

julia> p = C(cgrad(g))
```

Comment: You can also create a palette directly, through `Plots.palette(:viridis, 11)`.  This avoids the need to create a custom function - the last line becomes `plot([1:10], rand(10, 11); palette = palette(:viridis, 11))`.

Comment: Great, @AnshulSinghvi, I can add it to the answer if that is okay with you.